# PowerShell: Script won't count files older than 30 from last modified date

Tags: windows, powershell

all.

I'm stuck.  I have a PowerShell script which looks to a specific folder for files which are older than 30 days from the last modified date (additionally, it'll create the folder if it doesn't exist).  It creates the folder, it gives me the total files, it'll list all of the files in a test query, but it won't actually count the number of 30+ day old files.  I've tried several methods to get this count (some deriving from other solutions to delete old files from this site), but PowerShell just doesn't want to do it.

Here's my code so far...

```
$HomePath = $env:USERPROFILE
$CompanyFolder = "\Company"
$TimeSensativeFolder = "\TimeSensative"
$TimeSensativePath = $HomePath+$CompanyFolder+$TimeSensativeFolder
$OldFilesAmount = 0
$TotalFilesAmount = 0
$TimeLimit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
$StatusOK = "No old files were found in the time sensative folder."
$StatusCreated = "The time sensative folder was created."
$StatusError1 = "There were old files found in the time sensative folder!"
$StatusError2 = "Unable to create the time sensative folder!"

function MakeTimeSensativeFolder ($TimeSensativePath) {
    try {
        md $TimeSensativePath -Force -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host $StatusCreated
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host $StatusError2
    }
}

function CountOldFiles () {
    $OldFilesAmount = $OldFilesAmount + 1
}

if(!(Test-Path $TimeSensativePath -PathType Container)) {
    MakePHIFolder $TimeSensativePath
}
else {

}

try {
    $TotalFilesAmount = (Get-ChildItem $PHIPath -Recurse -File | Measure-Object).Count

    # I've tried this...
    Get-Item $PHIPath | Foreach {$_.LastWriteTime} -ErrorAction Stop
        if (Get-Content $_.LastWriteTime | Where-Object {$_ -gt $TimeLimit}) {
              CountOldFiles
        }

    # And I've tried this...
    Get-ChildItem -Path $PHIPath -Recurse -File | Foreach-Object {
        if (Get-Content $_.LastWriteTime | Where-Object {$_ -gt $TimeLimit}) {
           CountOldFiles
       }
    }

    # I've even tried this...
    Get-ChildItem $PHIPath -Recurse -File | ? {
       -not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $TimeLimit
    } | CountOldFiles

    # And this, as well...
    Get-ChildItem -Path $PHIPath -Recurse -File | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $TimeLimit} | CountOldFiles

}
catch {
    MakeTimeSensativeFolder $TimeSensativePath
}

# Used for testing.
<#
Get-ChildItem $TimeSensativePath -Recurse -File
Write-Host "TimeSensative folder exists:" $TimeSensativePathExists
Write-Host "Home TimeSensative path:" $TimeSensativePath
Write-Host "Old files found:" $OldFilesAmount
Write-Host "Total files found:" $TotalFilesAmount
Exit
#>

# Determining proper grammar for status message based on old file count.
if ($OldFilesAmount -eq 1) {
    $StatusError1 = "There was "+$OldFilesAmount+" old file of "+$TotalFilesAmount+" total found in the PHI folder!"
}
if ($OldFilesAmount -gt 1) {
    $StatusError1 = "There were "+$OldFilesAmount+" old files of "+$TotalFilesAmount+" total found in the PHI folder!"
}

# Give statuses.
if ($OldFilesAmount -gt 0) {
    Write-Host $StatusError1
}
else {
    Write-Host $StatusOK
}
```

Depending on which I tried, I would get no result or I'd get something like this:

```
Get-Content : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '12/22/2016 17' does not exist.
At C:\Users\nobody\Scripts\PS1\ts_file_age.ps1:54 char:14
+          if (Get-Content $_.LastWriteTime | Where-Object {$_ -gt $Tim ...
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (12/22/2016 17:String) [Get-Content], DriveNotFoundException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

In any instance, there's no old file count as I'm endeavoring to demand.

It's been a bit of a head scratcher.  Any advice?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Just an aisde on your spelling: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sensitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering files with last write time is easy enough. Like so,

```
$allFiles = gci 
$d = (Get-Date).adddays(-30)
$newFiles = @()
$oldFiles = @()
$allFiles | % { if ($_.lastwritetime -ge $d) { $newFiles +=$_ } else { $oldFiles += $_ } }
```

What's done here is that first all the files are set in a collection. This isn't mandatory, but one can browse the collection to check that it's been populated properly. This is useful in cases one has complex paths or exclusion filters.

The second step is just to get a `DateTime` that is used later to divide files into old and new ones. Just like the sample did, so nothing interesting here. Actually, there's one little thing. The date is -30 days, but hours, minutes and seconds are based on current time. So if there's really tight limit, consider using midnight time `([datetime]::Today).AddDays(-30)`

The third step is to declare two empty collections for new and old files.

The last step is to iterate through the `$allFiles` and check the last write time. If it's greater or equal to the cutpoint, add it into `$newFiles`, othervise `$OldFiles`.

After the last step, further processing should be simple enough.

Comment: Nice!  Then I can do $OldFilesAmount = $oldFiles.Count to acquire the count I need to output from the array it creates.  This is brilliant!  Much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I do to get (delete in this case) files older than X days:

```
$Days = 5
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$Days)
$CurrentDate = Get-Date

#This will delete all files older than 5 days

Get-ChildItem -Path $Workdir -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force
```

Comment: `$Daysback` is never set and `$DatetoDelete` is never used, so this snippet could use some refactoring.

Comment: I'm not trying to delete files.  I was using that as a for instance with examples I used.  I'm looking to output a count of old files.

Comment: well instead of `Remove-Item` you just use brackets and add `.Count`